# Alguém sabe fazer isso com PHP sem o jquery?

Tags: php

Eu preciso clicar no botão adicionar e colocar valores dentro de inputs no `PHP`.

```js
function InserirTelefone(){
  $('#telefones').append('<div>Nome: '+$('#nome').val()+' - Telefone: '+$('#telefone').val()+' </div>')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
    <form>
        <h2>Inserir Novo Telefone</h2>
        Nome: <input id="nome" type="text"/><br>
        Telefone: <input id="telefone" type="text"/><br>
        <input type="button" onclick="InserirTelefone()" value="Enviar" />
    </form>
    
    <div id="telefones">
        <h2>Telefones</h2>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Por favor, edite o código para ficar dentro de um bloco de código. Qualquer coisa, só selecionar tudo e clicar `ctrl+k`

Comment: Obrigado eu preciso clicar no botão adicionar e colocar valores dentro de inputs no php

Comment: Mas ainda está usando o Jquery... eu preciso usar o php puro

Comment: você sabe que o PHP é uma linguagem puramente servidor, né? Então não é possível escrever nele um evento de front-end sem usar JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta que formulário também envie as informações anteriores, assim você acrescenta o novo e dá um `echo`. Isso exigirá um novo campo:

```
<form>
  //..
  <input type="hidden" name="historico" value="HTMLENTITES(JSON({Valores Anteriores}))">
  //...
</form>
```

Dessa forma o PHP saberá o que existia antes, sem qualquer JQuery ou Javascript. Além disso é preciso notar o uso do `id` que deve ser trocado para `name`, afim de que as informações sejam enviadas para o PHP.

```
<?php
// Se o primeiro acesso, ele terá um histórico vazio:
$historico = [];

if(isset($_POST['nome'], $_POST['telefone'], $_POST['historico'])){

    // Define o historico (os dados que já foram mostrados anteriormente)
    $json = json_decode($_POST['historico'], true);
    if(json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE){
        $historico = $json;
    }

    // Acrescentas os dados atuais no historico
    $historico[] = ['nome' => $_POST['nome'], 'telefone' => $_POST['telefone']];
}
?>

<form action="#" method="post">
    <h2>Inserir Novo Telefone</h2>

    <label>Nome: <input name="nome" type="text"/></label><br>
    <label>Telefone: <input name="telefone" type="text"/></label><br>

    <!-- Define o "historico" com todos os valores já inseridos: -->
    <input type="hidden" name="historico" value="<?= htmlentities(json_encode($historico), ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8', false) ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>

<?php
// Repete por cada dado do "historico", tanto os antigos quanto os novos estão nessa variável.
foreach ($historico as $dados){
    if(isset($dados['nome'], $dados['telefone'])) {
        ?>
        <div>Nome: <?= htmlentities($dados['nome'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8', false) ?> -
            Telefone: <?= htmlentities($dados['telefone'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8', false) ?> </div>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Exatamente isso... Obrigado

Comment: Porém veja o erro...

Comment: @fabiobarros, qual erro?

Comment: Ele não ta escrevendo na tela

Comment: Qual versão do PHP está utilizando? Se for uma versão não suportada (< 5.6) ele poderá não funcionar. Não consegui reproduzir nenhum erro.

Comment: é o meu é 5.2 vou atualizar

Comment: atualizei pro 7.1.9 o seu exemplo vai mas o que eu criei não

Comment: Isso é porque está esquecendo de especificar um dos elementos, vise `'descricao' => $_POST['quantidade']` (em `$historico[]`). O `$dados['quantidade']` nunca vai existir, porque ele está com nome de  `descrição`, assim como o `descricao` nunca será usado.

Comment: alterei e nada ele não da erro mais nao aparece o que foi escrito

Comment: agora deu certo ...

Answer (score 0):

Se eu bem entendi, você quer pôr os valores listando-os em baixo certo?

Ora bem, se assim fôr, terá de criar uma base de dados (`mysql`), submeter os dados e recarregar a página de um dos seguintes modos: Ou por `POST` ou por `GET`. Após criar a base de dados, o código seria assim:

```
<?php
      $db_select=mysqli_connect('Localização do site ou "127.0.0.1" se for local','nome de utilizador ou "root" se for local','palavra passe ou " " se for local','nome da base de dados');
?>
<form method="POST">
        <h2>Inserir Novo Telefone</h2>
        Nome: <input name="nome" type="text"/><br>
        Telefone: <input name="telefone" type="text"/><br>
        <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Enviar" />
    </form>

<div id="telefones">
   <h2>Telefones</h2><br/>
   <?php
   $select = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM nome_tabela");
   while($mostra=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)){
      echo $mostra['nome']." - ".$mostra['telefone']. "<br/>;
   } ?>
</div>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
  $nome=$_POST['nome'];
  $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
  $insere=mysqli_query($db_select, "INSERT INTO nome_tabela(nome, telefone) VALUES('$nome', '$telefone')");
  echo "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

$_POST['item'], 'descricao' => $_POST['descricao'], $_POST['quantidade'], 'valorUni' => ['valorUni'], 'valortotal' => $_POST['valortotal']];



  }

?>



    Cadastro Produtos

      
          
            
              
            
            
              
            
            
              
            

            
              
            

            
              
            

          
        

        ">


        




    
         Item :       
         Descricao :  
         Quantidade : 
         Valor Uni  : 
         Valor Total:

Comment: Se você formatar seu código, ele pode ter uma aceitação melhor da comunidade